# What all is included in the contraption around Star Man?

Tags: spacex, falcon-heavy, tesla-roadster

In the [streaming video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w2F_nEI3b-E), we can see a mannequin sitting in a car.   It is fairly evident there is more to it than that, the cameras are clearly on some sort of supporting arms extending from the car, and it looks like there might be something additionally under the car.

I would really like to see an image - even a pre-launch image or an artist's concept image - of the entire object now in space.  I have seen the image of the car once it was mated to the payload adapter, but this was before Star Man was added, before the cameras were mounted, and so on.  Has any such image been published? If not, is there a more detailed description of this object and all of its attachments?

(For what it's worth, a partial motive for this question is a discussion around my office of why the suspension has not apparently decompressed.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Elon Musk has posted images](https://www.instagram.com/p/BezcvpzAgYI/) of the car with Starman seated in it. You can also see two camera mounts at the front and on the left side of the car.

[image: roadster with starman]

But the Roadster is not on its own in outer space. It's still attached to the second stage. So the whole thing looks more like this, as it's flying towards the asteroid belt:

[image]
<sup>Artist's Concept [Falcon Heavy Animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tk338VXcb24)</sup>

Someone tried to label the various camera bits in this image.

[image: Camera angles]
There is a Tesla Roadster model from Hot Wheels on the dash, with a tiny Starman sitting in it.

There is a [towel in the glove box](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/939005893634506752) to go along with the "Don't Panic" on the dash.

There is a plaque underneath the car, it is the X on the Payload Adapter that has 6000 signatures from SpaceX staffers.

There is a [Arch storage device](https://www.archmission.com/) with Isaac Asimov's Foundation device on it.

[image: Arch Storage device]

Comment: Worth noting there's an over the shoulder camera as well as it having engraved names as opposed to signatures on the plaque.

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a micro-Roadster with a micro-Starman in it on the dash of the Hot Wheels Roadster. And is there a nano-Roadster with a nano-Starman in that? How far does the recursion go?

Comment: How far?  At most six.  https://xkcd.com/878/

Answer (score 2):

Here is a photo of the roadster on the payload adapter. Starman and the cameras are all fitted at this point. There were no camera as far as we can tell that would provide footage of the entire assembly in space but this image shows the equipment. The front and left comers mounts are visible.
[image: Payload adapter]